# Map complex value objects in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, domain-driven-design, hibernate-xml-mapping

I've already asked this question on the [Hibernate's forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044084), but I thought I'd ask it here too.

I'm trying to map the following model while preserving the value semantics of the `TranslatedText` and `Translation` value objects:

[image]

## Both values as dependent objects

Ideally I'd map `TranslatedText` as a `<component>` within `Question` and `Translation` as a `<bag>` of `<composite-element>` within `TranslatedText`.

It would have been simple to map if `Question` was only referencing one `TranslatedText`, but since it references two I need some kind of discriminator based on the name of the property holding the value (`title` or `description`) in order to map the `Translation` with a foreing key composed of `(question_id,property_name,language_code)`.

One problem with that is that the `propertyName` isin't part of the model and shouldn't, but I haven't found a way to force Hibernate to insert a value that doesn't come from the model.

Therefore, I tried to change the model and introduce specialized `Title` and `Description` classes so that I'd have a `type` in there that I could use as a discriminator.

[image]

At the end that did not really help much:

```
  <component name="title" class="TranslatedText">

     <bag name="translations" table="Translation">
        <key>
           <!-- PROBLEM: Could not find a way to create a custom join expression on question.id and question.title.type in here. -->
        </key>

        <composite-element class="Translation">
           <!-- PROBLEM: Could not found a way to make Hibernate insert title.type from here, without having this value on the Translation object. -->
           <property name="languageCode" type="string" column="language_code"/>
           <property name="text" type="string"/>
        </composite-element>
     </bag>
  </component>
```

## TranslatedText with `<many-to-one>`

I managed to get something close to what I need by mapping `TranslatedText` as an entity within `Question` using a `<many-to-one>` and then map `Translation` as a collection of values within `TranslatedText`, but the main problem with that approach is that there is no easy way to get rid of the orphaned `TranslatedText` and `Translation`. I'd either have to do this with a DB trigger or a scheduled process.

## Conclusion

At this point I'm under the impression that Hibernate is not flexible enough to map the initial model with the proper semantics, but hopefully I'm wrong and there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to map them as values. However the next solution works and it might be helpful for you. I removed `TranslatedText` and linked `Question` directly with collection of `Translation`.

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @JoinTable
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    private List<Translation> titleTranslations;

    @JoinTable
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    private List<Translation>  descriptionTranslations;
}
```

The drawback here is that `Translation` has to be `Entity` class.

```
@Entity
public class Translation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String languageCode;
    private String text;
}
```

Comment: Well, `TranslatedText` is useful as it ensures only one translation per code so I can't just get rid of it, unless I enforce the rule with a DB constraint, but the model wouldn't be as expressive. I could use `Set<Translation>` instead if it was in java, but we can't do it since the model is actually written in ColdFusion (yes that horrible language), not java.

Comment: It is hard to understand your constraints without context but It is possible to have such relation by making all three classes as `@Entity` (each of them will have its own `@Id`). Is it ok for you? If so I can prepare such configuration.

Comment: Well, like I said I managed to do it already by mapping `TranslatedText` as an entity. However, I can't do `cascade-delete-orphan` in that case since I've used a `many-to-one`. Value objects are just simple immutable values like `Date` or `Integer`. Mapping them as hibernate components would fix the orphan problem. I'm actually surprised such common scenario is so hard to map.